# Change Email Notification Settings on a Google Sheet using Google Sheets API

Tags: google-sheets-api

Can someone point me at the API method for changing the "Email Notification Settings" on a Google Sheet?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

### Programmaticaly, you cannot change Google Sheets UI settings like `notification rules`

The closest you can do is to create a webhook that will watch for changes and implement the request of your choice (e.g. sending an email) when a certain change of a Drive File (inlcluding Google Sheets) occurs.

You can implement this by [watching for file changes with the Google Drive API](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/watch)
and receiving [push notifications](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/push#making-watch-requests).